# Problem downloading some urls with cURL on OSX

Tags: macos, homebrew

I have problem downloading some applications with homebrew. **I could get them when the download urls start with
https://**

**but curl fails when the urls start with,
ftp:// or http://**

For example, I want to install GMT (generic mapping tools) with homebrew on my Mac OS 10.7.4. and I get the error below. I think curl has problem downloading .tar.gz file, **but I have no problem downloading the same file with Firefox**.

```
$ brew install homebrew/science/gmt
==> Tapping homebrew/science
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-science'...
remote: Counting objects: 553, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (551/551), done.
remote: Total 553 (delta 2), reused 67 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (553/553), 432.61 KiB | 367 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), done.
Tapped 546 formulae (572 files, 2.9M)
==> Installing gmt from homebrew/homebrew-science
==> Installing dependencies for homebrew/science/gmt: cmake, libpng, gifl
==> Installing homebrew/science/gmt dependency: cmake
==> Downloading http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.3/cmake-3.3.1.tar.gz

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

As a workaround, I downloaded the `make-3.3.1.tar.gz` file with Firefox and copied it to `/Library/Caches/Homebrew/` and it worked. So I downloaded the .tar.gz files for each dependency. They all worked until downloading a .zip file `proj-datumgrid-1.5.zip` which looks like a data file used by the dependency `proj`.

Maybe I need to rename the .zip file downloaded somehow so that Homebrew recognize it. Or should I need to put it elsewhere
. How does homebrew use these files?

```
$ brew install homebrew/science/gmt
==> Installing gmt from homebrew/homebrew-science
==> Installing dependencies for homebrew/science/gmt: proj, libgeotiff, geos, readline, sq
==> Installing homebrew/science/gmt dependency: proj
==> Downloading http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-4.9.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/proj-4.9.1.tar.gz
==> Downloading http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-datumgrid-1.5.zip

curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
Error: Failed to download resource "proj--datumgrid"
```

Comment: Are you doing this from work? Is it possible, that you have to use a proxy server? To check, you could take a look at the Firefox settings or ask your administrator.

Comment: I'm at the university. Firefox uses Auto-detect proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running

```
brew update
```

and

```
brew updgrade
```

before

```
brew install homebrew/science/gmt
```

Usually many problems with formulas may be solved by simply updating & upgrading homebrew and its formulas!

Comment: Yes I did `brew update && upgrade` before `brew install homebrew/science/gmt`.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you are seeing a network issue. To test that, in the window where things errored out, try the host command to make sure DNS is happy and then try a basic curl to check the server is up.

```
host www.cmake.org
curl www.cmake.org | wc -l
```

The second command downloads the main page and counts the lines of text `curl` was able to retrieve. For me, I get:

```
www.cmake.org has address 66.194.253.19

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 28697    0 28697    0     0  53139      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 53142
     426
```

... so curl retrieves 426 lines of code.

At that point, you know the tools are fine and can check the actual resource that brew is trying to download - in this case

```
maac:log miike$ curl http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.3/cmake-3.3.1.tar.gz | wc -l
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 6423k  100 6423k    0     0   554k      0  0:00:11  0:00:11 --:--:--  799k
   25239
```

The above command seems the same as using firefox, but if you get similar results from the command line, retry the `brew install` with a verbose flag to get extra debugging information:

```
brew install -v homebrew/science/gmt
```

Comment: I tried this and got `$curl www.cmake.org | wc -l
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:15 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
       0`

Comment: @NasoloAndrianoelina Nice - then your networking is the problem and not the brew. Try `curl --connect-timeout 10 --retry 3 --verbose http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.3/cmake-3.3.1.tar.gz | wc -l
` but you'll likely need to ask a follow on question if you can't make sense of the output from that command. @ ping me here if you ask a new question on debugging curl :-)

Comment: Yes it was a networking problem and I could finally find a solution. The autodetect proxy was not working for curl and I asked the proxy from the administrator. From google: I added to the file '~/bash_profile'
something like this
'http_proxy="http://mycache.mydomain.com:8080"'
'export http_proxy'

Comment: Awesome news @NasoloAndrianoelina -  I would encourage you to answer that as a separate answer. I can sepe lots of people being stumped by this. Especially as MDM can set proxy settings for people behind the scenes and they may not be aware they are set.